# Codeigniter: How do I get a page to render with renderData & a login?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've built my login application using...

```
http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html
```

Before I added the login functionality... My CSS worked great when I had this code (but no login)...

[image]

Now after following the login tutorial I have this code...
[image]

And my the css doesn't get imported...

How do I pass the login $data & $renderData (which carries all of my css styling) together.

(Right now it's one or the other (the login data, or having a greatly formatted css doc)).

Added my render data function in case that would be helpful....

```
protected function _render($view,$renderData="FULLPAGE") {
    switch ($renderData) {
    case "AJAX"     :
        $this->load->view($view,$this->data);
    break;
    case "JSON"     :
        echo json_encode($this->data);
    break;
    case "FULLPAGE" :
    default         : 
    //static
    $toTpl["javascript"] = $this->javascript;
    $toTpl["css"] = $this->css;
    $toTpl["fonts"] = $this->fonts;

    //meta
    $toTpl["title"] = $this->title;
    $toTpl["description"] = $this->description;
    $toTpl["keywords"] = $this->keywords;
    $toTpl["author"] = $this->author;

    //data
    $toBody["content_body"] = $this->load->view($view,array_merge($this->data,$toTpl),true);

    //nav menu
    if($this->hasNav){
        $this->load->helper("nav");
        $toMenu["pageName"] = $this->pageName;
        $toHeader["nav"] = $this->load->view("template/nav",$toMenu,true);
    }
    $toHeader["basejs"] = $this->load->view("template/basejs",$this->data,true);

    $toBody["header"] = $this->load->view("template/header",$toHeader,true);
    $toBody["footer"] = $this->load->view("template/footer",'',true);

    $toTpl["body"] = $this->load->view("template/".$this->template,$toBody,true);


    //render view
    $this->load->view("template/skeleton",$toTpl);
     break;
}
}
```

Comment: Still having serious issues here. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Put $session_data['username'] in your renderData array then pass $renderData to your view. You will need to either send the renderData array to your index function, like you were previous, or generate it in a function within your controller. This should work unless there are significant differences between your pages/home view and the pages/home_view view. If that is the case you will need to merge the two views.